# Wrong putExtra - getStringExtra

Tags: android

A have a problem with `putExtra`!

```
int identif = context.getResources().getIdentifier("widget_button" + b, "id", context.getPackageName());        
System.out.println("dump piar: " + "widget_button" + b + "  " + serverList.get(i).id);

switch (b) {
    case 1:
        Intent widgetButton1 = new Intent(context, ServerDetailsActivity.class);
        widgetButton1.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_SERVER1);
        widgetButton1.putExtra("serverId", String.valueOf(serverList.get(i).id));
        PendingIntent configPendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, widgetButton1, 0);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(identif, configPendingIntent1);
        break;
    case 2:
        Intent widgetButton2 = new Intent(context, ServerDetailsActivity.class);
        widgetButton2.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_SERVER2);
        widgetButton2.putExtra("serverId", String.valueOf(serverList.get(i).id));
        PendingIntent configPendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, widgetButton2, 0);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(identif, configPendingIntent2);
        break;
    case 3:
        Intent widgetButton3 = new Intent(context, ServerDetailsActivity.class);
        widgetButton3.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_SERVER3);
        widgetButton3.putExtra("serverId", String.valueOf(serverList.get(i).id));
        PendingIntent configPendingIntent3 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, widgetButton3, 0);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(identif, configPendingIntent3);
                break;
}
```

Put strings to buttons and when I push second button:

```
Intent lastIntent = getIntent();

int serverId = Integer.parseInt(lastIntent.getStringExtra("serverId"));
System.out.println("dump serverId: " + serverId);
```

get wrong id. But I don't know why. If I touch second button, I given id "3" not "4"

```
dump piar: widget_button1  1
dump piar: widget_button2  4
dump piar: widget_button3  5
dump serverId: 3
```

Help pls. Thx.

**EDIT:**

If I remove putExtra, I can also get serverId with getStringExtra, but I don't know why.
(If I remove setOnClickPendingIntent, the button doesn't touchable.)

**SOLVED:**

If use this flag: `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`

Work fine!

```
PendingIntent configPendingIntent3 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, widgetButton3,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: Shouldn't you add 1 to `serverList.get(i).id`? Since it can start with 0.

Comment: post your log. (both outputs)

Comment: int b = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < serverList.size(); i++) {
No, I started with 1. This is not problem.

Comment: When I use putExtra print it to log. It's looks good. Just when I touch button given wrong numbers. getStringExtra("serverId") gives wrong number.